# Convert list into queue

Tags: list, queue, ocaml

How do I convert a list `v1::v2::vn::[]` into a queue?
This is all I've written until now:-

```
let fromList (l:'a list) : 'a queue =
  let queue = create () in
  let rec loop (z: 'a list) (q: 'a queue) : 'a queue = 
    begin 
      match z with 
      | [] -> None
      | hd :: tl ->
    end
```

Thank you!

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer reasonably. What does your queue type look like? What functions are available for manipulating your queues?

Comment: type 'a qnode = { v: 'a;
                  mutable next: 'a qnode option}

type 'a queue = { mutable head : 'a qnode option;
                  mutable tail : 'a qnode option }

Comment: and my functions are:

Comment: **get_tail (qn: 'a qnode) : 'a qnode option** (which finds the tail of the queue), **valid (q: 'a queue) : bool** (which checks if the queue is valid), **create () : 'a queue** (which creates a queue), **is_empty**,  **enq (x: 'a) (q: 'a queue) : unit** (add an element to the end of the queue), **deq (q: 'a queue) : 'a** (remove from the head of the queue),**to_list (q: 'a queue) : 'a list (q: 'a queue) : 'a list** (Retrieve the list of values stored in the queue, ordered head to tail.).

Comment: Note that you could use parentheses instead of `begin`...`end`, it saves a few key strokes and somewhat reduces the noise imho. Otoh, it's more explicit, so I guess it could be argued both ways.

Answer (score 1):

OK, you have a mutable queue type.

The idiomatic way to process a list imperatively is with `List.iter`.

It looks to me like you're planning to write your own recursive function `loop` to do this instead (possibly because this is homework). The first comment is that when writing imperative code like this, the idiomatic thing to do is to return `()` (the only value of type `unit`) rather than `None`. Your `loop` function will always return `()`, because it works by modifying the queue (imperatively).

The questions you have to answer for recursion (as I always point out) are:

- What do you need to do for an empty list?
- If the list is non-empty, what do you need to do with its head and tail?

When asked this way, the answers seem pretty obvious. But if not, a possible hint is that you want to call two functions that you already know about, one for the head and one for the tail of the list.

Comment: let from_list (l:'a list) : 'a queue = 
 let queue = create () in
  let rec loop (l: 'a list) (q: 'a queue) : 'a queue = 
  begin match l with 
  | [] -> ()
  | hd :: tl -> enq hd q; loop tl q
  end
 in loop l

Comment: It's hard to answer in this small space. Basically your `loop` takes two params but you seem to pass just one in your first call. Also, if your function ends with a call to `loop` then `loop` needs to return the queue. But it might be more idiomatic to say `loop l queue; queue` at the end (which is what I was expecting to see).